# Repartition HDD to give Ubuntu more space

Tags: windows, ubuntu

My Laptop came installed with Windows 10 and 500 GB of hard drive space. A few weeks ago I decided to try Ubuntu for a change, and created a 20GB partition for it.

Now, I want to give more space for the Ubuntu partition because I want to use Ubuntu OS permanently and probably migrate completely sometime soon from W10.

How do I resize the W10 partition FROM Ubuntu? Is it possible? Can I "unmount" the W10 partition and then resize it without breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be changing the size of your Ubuntu system, it would probably be best to use a Live CD so that you can resize the partitions without any issues with the mounted Ubuntu partition.  Once you've gotten the Live CD running, there should be a program installed called GParted.  This program can resize your Windows partition as well as your Ubuntu partition.  Do be careful though as GParted can do many other things, like wiping out all of your data if you're not careful, (normally it will alert you to such a thing first though).  For the most part GParted is fairly intuitive, so it shouldn't be hard for you to figure it out since you've been using Ubuntu for a while.

Also of note is the fact that Ubuntu is capable of reading and writing to NTFS, (Windows) partitions.  Before I started building systems on my own, I would give Linux 50-100G to play with as it can use the NTFS partition for storage.  Linux can usually read Windows partitions, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can. As you suggested yourself, you need to unmount it first (why would it be mounted in the first place though?). With utility like `gparted`, it will make use of `ntfsresize` in ntfs-3g to resize the filesystem, then adjust the partition size accordingly in the partition table.**

However, Disk Management in Windows (as of 10, at least) support resizing the NTFS partition "online", that is, you can even shrink the system partition with it booted. It could be more reliable than `ntfsresize` (I suppose Microsoft knows NTFS better than some third party).

`I want to give more space for the Ubuntu partition` can be tricky though. It's unlikely that you can *simply* extend it forward, from, for example:

```
Windows (250GB) | Empty (50GB) | Ubuntu (200GB)
```

to

```
Windows (250GB) | Ubuntu (250GB)
```

`gparted` is probably able to move the Ubuntu partition forward bit by bit first, and then extend it till the end of the drive. However, be expected that this could potentially take a long time (depending on the size of the current size partition) and break booting.

Make sure  for the Ubuntu part you do it with a (gparted) live medium.

---

**You can also do those step by step manually. Though if you don't really know about partition table you may not prefer that, it's at least good to be aware that "filesystem (size)" and "partition (size)" are separate things.